# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out concrete5

Tags: php, sql, doctrine

This is a question that has been asked before, as I can see from looking through the archives. However, I have looked through several of these and none are able to offer the specific advice I need to resolve this problem.

With some assistance I have been attempting to set up a fresh Concrete5 CMS installation on a web hosting platform. With a lot of back and forth it seems to have reached a relatively stable state of being broken but at least throwing up useful error messages that have been aiding in the process.

My webhost is particularly unhelpful as they do not currently employ anyone, even in their technical support staff, who seems to be aware of how the back-end of their servers actually function. Not one of them seemed to know at all what I was talking about when I asked about php configurations or where error logs were located. Their control panel leaves a great deal to be desired and beyond that they are just beyond frustrating to work with. Which leaves me relatively high and dry.

tl;dr: My webhosting tech support couldn't help with this. I'm hoping someone here might be able to shed some light.

Here is what I'm getting now from when I try to access www.mysite.com/concrete5/

> Doctrine \ DBAL \ Driver \ PDOException (2002)
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

**/~truncated~/htdocs/concrete5/concrete/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php**

```
 * @throws PDOException in case of an error.
 */
public function __construct($dsn, $user = null, $password = null, array $options = null)
{
    try {
        parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $password, $options);
        $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, array('Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement', array()));
        $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (\PDOException $exception) {
        throw new PDOException($exception);
    }
}``

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function exec($statement)
{
    try {
        return parent::exec($statement);
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Assume that I have no actual console access to the server I am hosting with. They don't provide command line access, which in my opinion is kind of ridiculous. I'm hoping I can find the answer somewhere in the configuration files, otherwise I'm not sure what I'll be able to do.